# Writing Virtual RS232 Port Emulator that runs in user code

Tags: windows, device-driver

Is there any way to write a virtual RS232 Port Emulator that doesn't have to be installed as a device driver?

What I'd like to have is a program that emulates a physical hardware device.  It tells the OS that it is port COM1.  Other programs see COM1 and open it using code like the .NET `SerialPort` class.  Once the connection is established, the emulator begins emulating the device.

I know there are virtual COM port drivers out there that can do this, but my boss does not want to use them.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a sample UMDF Virtual serial port driver sample that Microsoft provides](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Virtual-serial-driver-8383ea42). It's not kernel mode, so this might get past the reasoning for not wanting to be a "driver" (which I read as "kernel driver" here). At some point you need to interact with the IO subsystem to make your exposed COM port a device (even if it's just a software device) so I think this is about as high of level as you'll get from what you are describing.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look the code over & show it to my boss for his opinion.

Comment: Yep - the UMDF would be the best way to go. I'm not sure the reservation for a proper driver but in this case you are at least isolated from BSODs, which is probably the #1 reason to stay out of the kernel IMO.